# Show contentpage that called local notification when notification is clicked

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I'm relatively new to Xamarin and have gotten to a point in my application where I want to have notifications, I'm using local notifications to show the user that they have received a message from someone in my application. While I can get the notification to show, when it clicks it either shows nothing or it "restarts" the application (takes the user back to the login page).

How do I get the notification to show a set page, such as my contacts page when the notification is clicked on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get the notification to show a set page, such as my contacts page when the notification is clicked on?

`Xamarin.Forms` only has one activity, no matter how many pages you created, they are created on `MainActivity`.

But still we can have a workaround to work it out:

1. Create your local notification with an intent to indicate which page you want to navigate to(`Page1`):

   ```
   Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);
   Intent intent = new Intent(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   // if we want to navigate to Page1:
   bundle.PutString("pageName", "Page1");
   intent.PutExtras(bundle);
   PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, 0, intent, 0);
   builder.SetContentTitle(title)
          .SetContentText(text)
          .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
          .SetContentIntent(pIntent);
   var manager = (NotificationManager)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService("notification");
       manager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
   ```
2. In `MainActivity.cs` inside `OnCreate` we use reflection to set the App's `MainPage`:

   ```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
       TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
       ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

       base.OnCreate(bundle);

       global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
       var myApp = new App();
       var mBundle = Intent.Extras;
       if (mBundle != null)
       {
           var pageName = mBundle.GetString("pageName");
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName))
           {
               //get the assemblyQualifiedName of page
               var pageAssemblyName = "Your_PCL_Name." + pageName+",Your_PCL_Name";
               Type type = Type.GetType(pageAssemblyName);
               if (type != null)
               {
                   var currentPage = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                   //set the main page
                   myApp.MainPage = (Page)currentPage;
               }

           }
       }

       //load myApp
       LoadApplication(myApp);
   }
   ```

Notes: this workaround modifies the `MainPage` of your PCL's `App`, if you have usage for this property, please modify the logic properly.