# How to navigate to a particular page when user taps on a Local Notification in Xamarin Forms app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uilocalnotification, localnotification

Hi am developing a Xamarin Forms app. i have implemented local notifications in the app. When the notification has fired, upon clicking the notification it has to navigate to a particular page. 
In iOS project in Appdelegate.cs i wrote this method

```
    public async  override void ReceivedLocalNotification(UIApplication application, UILocalNotification notification)
```

which will fire when the user taps on the notification. here i need to navigate to a page. Here i wrote the below line of code

```
            App.Current.MainPage  = new NavigationPage(new FavoritesPage());
```

It is navigating to the Favorites page but it is just displaying a blank page. OnNavigatedTo method is not calling for the FavoritesViewModel and in the Onnavigated to am calling a method which takes id(this id comes from the notification) as parameter to get a particular favorite
Here two questions
1) How to navigate to a Specific page
2) How to pass a parameter along with the page navigation. 
Can someone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For 1:

You want to push to a new Page, but what you did is replacing the app's MainPage. please try `PushAsync`. You can subscribe a `MessagingCenter` in App:

```
public App ()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "Push", async (sender, favoriteID) =>
    {
        var favorite = new FavoritesPage();
        favorite.FavoriteID = favoriteID;
        await (MainPage as NavigationPage).PushAsync(favorite, true);
    });
}
```

This Lambda will fire when you call `MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "Push", "01");`
The string **01** here is the ID what I want to push.

### For 2:

Before I push to a new page, I define a property called `FavoriteID` in this page, then I pass the string using method above.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. How can i do the same steps in android? Which method will fire when the user taps on the notification in android?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar When you write the Send method, the Subscribe will fire.

Comment: Am asking about, in iOS this method     public async  override void ReceivedLocalNotification(UIApplication application, UILocalNotification notification)
will trigger whenever the user taps on the notification correct. Similarly what method will trigger in android when the user taps on the notification? Is there any method in android which is similar to ReceivedLocalNotification

Comment: @SanthoshKumar I find a thread may be help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47465959/8354952). It's about how to create a notification and trigger it. You just need to modify the push method in if statement.

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for your reply. I just need a method which will fire when the user taps on the notification. Am creating the local notifications from PCL. I just need a method in MainActivity.cs which should trigger when the user taps on the notification

Comment: @SanthoshKumar If you don't implement notification on each platform, whether you use an extension to achieve this effect? please post some code about how you implement this in PCL. Then we can analyze how to trigger it, But I recommend you post a new thread if you can make it properly on iOS. Then I can give a new answer to see how we can do it.

Comment: Hey am using xam.plugins.Notifier nuget package to send local notifications, below is the code to send a notification                     CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show(fav.ExtendedAttributes["Name"] + fav.Key+ AppResources.NotificationDisplayText, fav.Key, int.Parse(fav.Key), DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30));

Comment: @SanthoshKumar I have seen this plugin, after seeing its source code in Android, I find it didn't implement the trigger method. I recommend you to use a dependency service to implement this effect on each native platform. You can refer to the thread I just mentioned. It's not difficult.

Comment: Land, Is there any another way to get this done. similar to iOS?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Android is different, we must add `PendingIntent.GetActivity(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, 0, intent, 0);` to set the `Extras` and then when the app loaded in the `OnCreate()` we can get that to point out which page we want to push.

Comment: Land, am getting some Id in Notification, how can i get that id here?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar It is set when this notification is created. It is different from iOS.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar I don't think we can do it with this plugin. The author didn't give us an entrance. Or you can try to detect which platform user uses, on Android we can do it what "Elvis" said. The code from Android can achieve your effect easily. I also think you should open a new thread asking how to trigger using this plugin, it can also help other community members find correct answers.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Hi SanthoshKumar, did you solve it? If you truly don't understand how to do it. I can try to make a small sample for you.

Comment: Land Lu,  It would be great if you can make a sample for me

Comment: @SanthoshKumar [Here](https://github.com/lt0526/LocationNotificationsDemo) is a small sample.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Did it help you?

Comment: Thank you so much Land. I can able to navigate it.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar This sample has method navigating to a new page on Android.

Comment: Which Sample Land?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Run my sample [here](https://github.com/lt0526/LocationNotificationsDemo) on Android.

Comment: Thanks Land. I will try it and i will reach out to you if i need any help

Answer (score 0):

Use MessagingCenter, set ContentPage type or url for MessagingCenter.Send, then MessagingCenter.Subscribe & load

Comment: am very new to xamarin. It would be great if you can provide a chunk of code to get this done

Comment: take a look at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/