# How to use Dependency Injection to implement Flyoutnavigation in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

how would I use Dependency Injection to use the [Flyoutnavigation](https://github.com/Clancey/FlyoutNavigation) for my iOS project.

I have decided to stick with the default MasterDetailPage for Android as it doesn't look as bad as iOS.

This is what I have done so far:

**In PCL**

IMainPage.cs:

```
public interface IMainPage
{
    Page GetMainPage();
}
```

App.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        MainPage = DependencyService.Get<IMainPage>().GetMainPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

**In Android**

MainPage_Android.cs:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MainPage_Android))]
namespace ProjectName.Droid
{
    public class MainPage_Android : MasterDetailPage, IMainPage
    {
        private NavigationPage detail;
        private MasterPage master;

        public Page GetMainPage()
        {
            MasterDetailPage mdp = new MasterDetailPage();

            //Master
            master = new MasterPage();
            MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
            mdp.Master = master;

            //Detail
            detail = new NavigationPage(new Home())
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#01A0E1"),
                BarTextColor = Color.White
            };
            mdp.Detail = detail;

            return mdp;
        }
    }
}
```

**In iOS**

- **I am stuck here.. How do I return a page using the Flyoutnavigation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use default style on Android and custom style on iOS, you can try to make a custom renderer for MasterDetailPage on iOS. Then embed your `Flyoutnavigation`.

This is my iPad renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MainPageRenderer))]
namespace FlyoutNavigationDemo.iOS
{
    public class MainPageRenderer : TabletMasterDetailRenderer
    { 
         //put your Flyoutnavigation's code here
    }
}
```

Since `Flyoutnavigation` has too much code. I make a small sample for you, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/lt0526/FlyoutNavigationDemo) for more details.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. When I load and compile your project though, I get these errors: 

1.
Metadata file 'D:\New folder (2)\FlyoutNavigationDemo-master\FlyoutNavigationDemo\FlyoutNavigationDemo\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\FlyoutNavigationDemo.dll' could not be found FlyoutNavigationDemo.iOS
    
and also 2.
The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. FlyoutNavigationDemo

Comment: @Bracefor Please try to delete the bin and obj folder, then run again.

Comment: Okay, should I delete all the bin and obj folders from every project?

Comment: @Bracefor yeah, you can try.

Comment: I fixed it! All I had to do was change the target framework back down to .NET Standard 1.6.

Comment: But Something really weird is going on with the project that you created? I can see the FlyoutNavigation works, but when I pull out the menu from the left (hand gesture left to right) the MasterDetailPage comes out?

Comment: Okay, so I was messing around, and for some reason, when I changed "TabletMasterDetailRenderer" to "PhoneMasterDetailRenderer" everything seems to be working fine? Why on earth is that?

Comment: Now I have a problem though. How do I load the pages I have created in my (Portable) project folder in the FlyoutNavigation menu?

Comment: @Bracefor Glad you did it. If you want to return to PCL you can use `MessagingCenter` to push a new page. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335931/8354952) is a thread may help you.

Comment: Hey, sorry, but you said "If you return to PCL". Does that mean the project is currently a shared project? Or a .NET Standard? Also, how would I achieve it then if I stayed with the current project type?

Comment: @Bracefor Are you using forms? This solution can help you go back to forms(e.g. page) from native view.

Comment: Yes I am using forms. Would I use messaging center to push a new page from native view in a shared project?

Comment: @Bracefor Yes, follow my step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335931/8354952).

Comment: Hi, but can I load a ContentPage in a UIViewController? Because I would like for when the user selects an option in the menu, for it to show the ContentPages that I have already created in the shared code project (e.g. The Home page should be able to be used on Android and iOS) If you could, could you please provide the code on this in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Bracefor My solution is: subscribe a MessagingCenter in your MasterDetailPage, when you want to push a new page in viewcontroller(Tap an option in the menu), send a MessagingCenter. After receiving it, you can do what you want in forms.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but in the case of when it is iOS, the entire screen is just the UIViewController, and so when I change the navigation page, it wont work?? I need to somehow place a NavigationPage within the UINavigationController?

Comment: @Bracefor On iOS, if you want to push to a new viewController, you should create a navigationViewController wrapping the VCs. So on forms, use navigationPage wrapping your MasterDetailPage’s detail page. (NavigationPage corresponding to NavigationViewController just as ContentPage to ViewController)

Comment: I asked the question in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490965/using-a-page-made-in-xamarin-forms-shared-project-in-my-ios-project as I am probably not explaining or understanding correctly :)

Comment: Could you maybe explain what you mean there please? I am really stuck.

Comment: @Bracefor I understand your issue now. It may be a little difficult to achieve that. I can get the renderer from PCL's page now, but it seems a little weird and the control on page can't be shown on native scenario. I need some time to find out whether we can do that. Also another solution is find another project that supports Forms.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much. I think I achieved something, but the outcome is really weird... I used the solution given here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41976/how-to-get-uiviewcontroller-associated-with-a-page to create a UIViewController of the pages, but when I do that, the pages are extremely buggy, and only the title and tabbed pages show? I’m really new, so excuse me if I seem silly to do that!

Comment: @Bracefor Yes, this is which I used. As I said it seemed weird.

Comment: I think I may have found a work-around: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/getting-started-with-radsidedrawer-for-xamarin-forms What do you think? I wish however that the MasterDetailPage was more customizable.

Comment: Hey, that solution didn't work for me, could you maybe check out my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525241/editing-and-using-the-xamarin-forms-source-code?noredirect=1